# Does enforcing a password complexity requirement in randomly generated passwords make them more secure?

Tags: security, passwords

I came across some code that looks approximately like this:

```
function generatePassword() {
  let password;
  do {
    password = generateRandomString();
  } while (!checkPasswordComplexity(password));
  return password;
}
```

Assume `generateRandomString()` returns a truly random string of the desired set of characters, and `checkPasswordComplexity()` checks that the password contains some predefined minimum number of uppercase/lowercase/numbers/special characters.

Basically it tries to generate a random password, checks certain complexity requirements, if the check fails it tries again.

First question:

Is this actually more secure than just returning the first result from `generateRandomString`?

Second question:

If this actually is a good practice, is there a more efficient (but still secure) way to directly generate a password that satisfies the complexity requirement?

Answer (score 0):

To begin answering my own questions:

First question:

On one hand, a password cracker might start with less complex candidate passwords. On the other hand, if the cracker knows your complexity requirements this is actually reducing the search space. In practice I don't know which is better.

Second question:

If you require, say, 2 special characters in a password of length 10, then randomly pick 2 characters from the special character set, then place them in random positions in the final password. Then fill the remaining 8  positions with random characters from the entire set of characters.